# Producing XML of list of object which contains list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have object structure in which I have a list of Layer1 elements and this Layer1 contains a list of Layer2 arguments like below (getter, setters, methods ommited):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElement(name = "layer1")
    private List<Layer1> layer1 = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "layer1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Layer1 {

   @XmlElement(name = "layer2")
   private List<String> layer2;
}
```

I am trying to marshall this into XML in this way:

```
public void marshall(){
try {
   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
   Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
   jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
   jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root.getlayer1(), System.out);
}
```

But it's not working and generates an exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:567)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:467)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
```

I want have below output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <layer1>
        <layer2>value1</layer2>
        <layer2>value12</layer2>
        <layer2>value13</layer2>
    </layer1>
    <layer1>
        <layer2>value123</layer2>
        <layer2>value1231</layer2>
    </layer1>
    <layer1>
        <layer2>value12</layer2>
        <layer2>value1</layer2>
     </layer1>
</root>
```

Please give me some advice how to annotate my case. I was reading other similar topics, but I still can't make a proper solution.

Comment: Looking at your desired XML output, you probably mean  
`jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, System.out);`  
instead of  
`jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root.getlayer1(), System.out);`

Comment: Omg, such a obvious mistake and it took me so much time before writing this question... Thank you, works fine now